# The use of Wget for Downloading Oracle

Tags: ubuntu, wget, oracle-11g

My basic configuration:
Ubuntu 16.04
Wget  1.17.1

when I use the command

```
$ wget --http-user=myuser --http-password=mypasswrd https://download.oracle.com/otn/linux/oracle11g/R2/linux.x64_11gR2_database_1of2.zip
```

to download the oracle11g, the terminal shows the following output:

```
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Permanently  
Location: https://download.oracle.com/errors/download-fail-1505220.html [following]    
--2019-04-07 11:42:05--  https://download.oracle.com/errors/download-fail-1505220.html   
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|23.45.156.151|:443... connected.   
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK   
Length: 5307 (5.2K) [text/html]   
Saving to: ‘linux.x64_11gR2_database_1of2.zip.2’    
linux.x64_11gR2_database_1o 100%[=======================>]   5.18K  --.-KB/s    in 0s         
2019-04-07 11:42:10 (737 MB/s) - ‘linux.x64_11gR2_database_1of2.zip.2’ saved [5307/5307]
```

When `du -sh linux.x64_11gR2_database_1of2.zip`, the linux.x64_11gR2_database_1of2.zip.2 only has 8.0K!!!

And I have  clicked on "Accept License".

Appreciate any comment.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at [what gets downloaded](https://download.oracle.com/errors/download-fail-1505220.html):

you see this:

> Sorry!
>   In order to download products from Oracle Technology Network you must agree to the OTN license terms.
>   Be sure that...
>   Your browser has "cookies" and JavaScript enabled.
>   You clicked on "Accept License" for the product you wish to download.
>   You attempt the download within 30 minutes of accepting the license.

In practice, in the page where you agree wit the licence, Oracle sets a cookie, and this is checked when you download. You can extract the cookie(s) from your browser and reuse them with Wget (see the `--load-cookies` paramater), but it may not be worth the trouble.